# Two or more file input

Tags: php, html, file, file-upload

I have more than one input which are of type file

```
<form  name="vform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
  <input type=file name='thumbs1' />
  <input type=file name='thumbs2' />
  <input type=file name='thumbs3' />
  ... etc
</form>
```

let say i got the count of file input=3

```
$i = 1;
while($i <= 3)
{
   $thumb = "thumbs".$i;
   $fileName = $_FILES['$thumb']['name'];
   $tmpName  = $_FILES['$thumb']['tmp_name']; 
   $filePath = "directory/";

   if(move_uploaded_file($tmpName, $filePath)){echo " ";}else{echo " ";}

   $i++;
}
```

What happens here is that only the first one got the filename, but not one of them move to the expected directory or anywhere else.

Is there a specific way to declare when dealing with multiple file input?

Comment: Visit http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php

Comment: If you are using HTML5, you can use `<input type='file' multiple='multiple'>` instead of different file boxes.

Comment: @KaranPunamiya I need to do it separately because there is other element associated with that file, I didn't post it here to simplify my question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the single quotes from `$_FILES['$thumb']` and change it to `$_FILES[$thumb]`

PHP will not parse variables within the single quotes `' '`.

On `move_uploaded_file` function you need to specify the file name for destination before moving

```
$i = 1;
while($i <= 3)
{
   $thumb = "thumbs".$i;
   $fileName = $_FILES[$thumb]['name'];
   $tmpName  = $_FILES[$thumb]['tmp_name']; 
   $filePath = "directory/";

   if(move_uploaded_file($tmpName, $filePath.$fileName)){echo " ";}else{echo " ";}

   $i++;
}
```

Comment: it works perfect. Thank you so much :)
simply removing the quotes in $_FILES[$thumb]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the single quotes in the `files` will be the problem, try out this

```
$i = 1;
while($i <= 3)
{
   $thumb = "thumbs".$i;
   $fileName = $_FILES[$thumb]['name'];
   $tmpName  = $_FILES[$thumb]['tmp_name']; 
   $filePath = "directory/".$filename;

   if(move_uploaded_file($tmpName, $filePath)){echo " ";}else{echo " ";}

   $i++;
}
```